# Remove one element from each row of a 2d int array

Tags: java, arrays

I have a 2D int array that I need to delete 1 element from each row, but they aren't necessarily in the same column.

For example, if I have the following array:

```
[[1, 2, 3],
[4, 5, 6],
[7, 8, 9]]
```

I would want the following output if I chose to delete the elements 2, 6, 8:

```
[[1, 3],
[4, 5],
[7, 9]]
```

The only answer I have found that closely resembles a solution was an answer to delete a whole column from a 2D array. I also understand ArrayLists would make my life extremely easy, but I am using a 2D array to make my life easier in a different area.

Comment: What part specifically do you need help with? Do you know how to "remove an element from an array"?

Comment: Why not loop on the 2D array twice - the first time for every row: switch between the element you want to delete and the last element. Second step: delete the last column (Unless the order of the element is important and if so please note that in the question)

Comment: `IntStream.range(0, arr.length).map(r -> Arrays.stream(arr[r]).filter(x -> x != delete[r]).toArray()).toArray(int[][]::new)`

Comment: @DavidWinder That just wouldn't work as I want to keep the order the same.

Comment: @Carcigenicate The problem is how I want to keep the order the same within the array but get rid of one of the elements from each row.

Comment: Don’t you have the solution you need in the link I posted?